# React native-iOS, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, react-native

I did research about resolving this issue. Whenever i try to run the command

```
react-native run-ios
```

in terminal, i get the same error. Xcode (8.2.1) says

```
ld: library not found for -lRCTBlob
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And the error which i am getting in terminal

[image]

I already changed the project settings in xcode as:

[image]

Then also i am getting the same error.
Suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

remove **BUILD folder from IOS directory**
and run 
**react-native run-ios**

Comment: I removed BUILD folder from iOS directory, but it still showing same error.

Comment: make sure all library linked successfully with IOS..
otherwise remove your IOS folder and do react-native-upgrade